# WiX Burn bundle installer - Handling upgrade and un-installing exe packages

Tags: wix, exe, upgrade, uninstallation, bootstrapper

I am working on a bundle installer with WiX that includes an MSI package and a few EXE packages.  For EXE packages, it seems that a WiX bundle installer can handle either upgrading or un-installing, but not both.  Is it possible to create a WiX bundle installer with ExePackages that will handle both upgrading and un-installing the ExePackages?

The first issue I ran into was that when un-installing my bundle, it would only un-install the MSI package and would leave the EXE-installed packages on the system.  I found that the solution to that was to put a DetectCondition in the ExePackage element.  However, the DetectCondition seems to interfere with upgrading the ExePackage.  With the DetectCondition in there, the log from an upgrade install shows "Error 0x80070002: Failed to find payload" for the Exe package.

For example, an ExeBundle section with the DetectCondition looks something like this:

```
<ExePackage Id="BLAH_INSTALLER"
              SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\InputBin\SetupBlah.exe"
              Compressed="yes"
              InstallCommand="/install /norestart /quiet"
              UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet"
              RepairCommand="/repair /quiet"
              DetectCondition="BlahPresent"
              Cache="always" >
    <dep:Provides Key="IntelISA" Version="5.1.10.160" />
  </ExePackage>
```

And the BlahPresent logic:

```
<util:FileSearch
  Id="Blah_Installed"
  Path="[ProgramFiles64Folder]\Blah\blah.exe"
  Variable="BlahPresent"
  Result="exists" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this DetectCondition in an example, which seems to enable both upgrading and un-installing an ExePackage in a bundle:

```
DetectCondition="WixBundleInstalled=1"
```

This is how it would appear in an ExePackage element:

```
<ExePackage Id="BLAH_INSTALLER"
              SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)\InputBin\SetupBlah.exe"
              Compressed="yes"
              InstallCommand="/install /norestart /quiet"
              UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet"
              RepairCommand="/repair /quiet"
              DetectCondition="WixBundleInstalled=1"
              Cache="always" >
```